# How to interpret time and individual fixed effects?

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model

In a panel data study, I understand that individual fixed effects allow to study the time series of the data, and time fixed effects the cross-section. What about both? what is the meaning of the beta coefficient in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Including fixed effects (time, indidvidual or both) does not change the meaning of beta coefficients. 
You could just see fixed effects as a means to control for shocks in different time periods (i.e. time fixed effects) or individual characteristics that we cannot control for (i.e. individual fixed effects).